# Excel if statement returning value unformatted

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 check boxes, if my budget check box is selected I would like to display value X. If my potential check box is selected, I would like to display value Y.

```
=IF(P7=TRUE,IF(B23=D14,J13,""),IF(C23=D14,J13,"")&""&IF(P7=FALSE,IF(B23=D19,J18,""),IF(C23=D19,J18,"")))
```

The issue I have is the value that comes through is correct, but it is to 11 decimal places and not formatted as currency. So I have tried to format the source and the result cell but still no luck. The result comes through as below:

[image: a]

I am really quite stuck.

Comment: A Excel function ever returns only unformatted values[1]. The cell contains the format. Just format the cell which contains the formula as you need. [1] Or formatted text strings, but this is not what you want, because those strings cannot be included in further calculations.

Comment: I have already tried to format the cell with the formula as currency and no change.

Comment: Just as the value is based on the state of the checkboxes, so must the conditional formatting.

Comment: Just tried this, still no luck - When I go into formatting the number stays the same length, so normally you reduce decimal places you can see this happen in the editor, but this does not happen in this case.

Comment: Argh, had not seen that you are already creating a text string by concatenating with &. Maybe the formula `=IF(P7=TRUE,IF(OR(B23=D14,C23=D14),J13,""),IF(OR(B23=D19,C23=D19),J18,""))`
better fulfill your requirements?

Comment: @AxelRichter, that is perfect. Thank you for your help. My formulas are going to get longer and more complicated as I progress through the year so this is really scalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If P7 is not true you always return a string because of the `&""&IF` in the middle of your expression. Strings are not subject to cell formatting.

I think you could make this a lot simpler with the use of AND() and OR().